# React - Module parse failed: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs

Please help me on this issue

const path = require('path');
// const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

```
module.export = {
entry:'./src/index.js',
output:{
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
module: {
loaders: [{
  test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',

    query: {
       presets: ['es2015', 'react']
    }
}]
},

devServer: {
    port: 8000,
    contentBase: 'build',
    inline: true,
    mode: 'development'
},

}
```

Comment: Can you share the error snapshot?

Comment: Can you add more context into what you're trying to accomplish and what it is failing to do? You should also tag this question with `webpack` and `babel-loader`